AWS account aliases and finding them with credentials
I'm trying to find my account's alias. I've seen a lot of responses elsewhere saying it's not possible without a credential but they just stop there. Well, I do have credentials. In my call to list-account-aliases I get nothing in response (an empty array). However, that's not possible because I'm looking at the alias in my access portal.
var sessionCreds = new SessionAWSCredentials(KeyId.Text, AccessKey.Text, SessionToken.Text);
using var stsClient = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(sessionCreds);
using var iamClient = new AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient(sessionCreds);

var identity = await stsClient.GetCallerIdentityAsync(new GetCallerIdentityRequest());
var aliases = await iamClient.ListAccountAliasesAsync(); // empty array in response

What I'm seeing in my access portal:

How do I find this 'Production' name? I'm using the access keys link values for the appropriate account. I've validated the account number in get-caller-identity matches the account number for this 'Production' account. I'm making a user client and need to reassure the user they're in the right account so just spitting an account number at them is not useful or helpful. This isn't the first time I've had this problem but it's been a nice to have and not a requirement. However, now it's a requirement so I can't just ignore it. I don't understand why AWS is so cagey with aliases.

I don't know where that Production name is from, but it's not an account alias. If you showed more of the screenshot we might be able to help you understand what that value is and how you could query it. An account alias is always lower case, and it has to be unique, as in no other AWS account can have the same alias.

Hi @MarkB. It's the account names from the portal page. No different than the name of an account when you go into an org > add account > account name value. So that's not an alias? OK, what is it? How can I get it? First result when I look up how to get an account name is going after aliases.
And because I type these things and look them up to fact check myself. Looks like this can be gotten from a simple describe-account call. Thank you for pointing out the distinction and making me look closer.

So that's part of the AWS Organizations structure, where you give each sub-account in your organization a name to differentiate them within your organization. That's different from the account alias, which actually generates a login page using the alias name, and has to be unique across all accounts on AWS so that the login page URL doesn't conflict.

Thanks to Mark B this can be gotten from a describe-account call to the AWS organizations API instead. Name is a field returned in that call and is the account name.
